# PHP to find a child node

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML file - **for example:**

```
<slideshow>
    <image src="myPhotos/1.jpg" desc="Sample" />
    <image src="myPhotos/2.jpg" desc="Sample" />
    <image src="myPhotos/3.jpg" desc="Sample" />
    <image src="myPhotos/4.jpg" desc="This is image 4" />
    <image src="myPhotos/5.jpg" desc="This is image 5" />
    <image src="myPhotos/6.jpg" desc="This is image 6" />
    <image src="myPhotos/7.jpg" desc="This is image 7" />
    <image src="myPhotos/8.jpg" desc="This is image 8" />
</slideshow>
```

Alright, so what I need help with is (*without explaining my whole project*). I want PHP to find a child node in an XML file by it's attribute and that attribute is "**src**".

Then once it finds the correct attribute - then I need to jump to the "**desc**" 
 in the **same child though**! and only change the "**desc**" attribute.

I have this working with the code below - but the only issue is that if my attribute values are the same, it changes all the "**desc**".

### Here is my full PHP script:

```
<?php

    $currentTextHeading = $_POST['currentTextHeading'];
    $newTextHeading = $_POST['newTextHeading'];

    $dom = new DomDocument;
    $dom->load('myPhotos.xml');

    $xpath = new DomXPath($dom);

    $cAttribs = $xpath->query('//*[@desc= "'.$currentTextHeading.'"]');
    foreach ($cAttribs as $entry) {
        $entry->setAttribute('desc', $newTextHeading);
    }

    $dom->save('myPhotos.xml');

    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    die();

?>
```

### Breaking it down...

I want to first look for the "**src**" attribute because that attribute will always be unique, then change the "**desc**" of that child and only that one!

The user will be changing these "**attributes**" by a html text form.

Comment: You already know everything to make that work. The issue is simply that your code is not querying for the src attribute. You are querying for all nodes with a certain desc attribute value. So for "Sample" you get the first three nodes. You change these in the loop to hold the new value. So instead of querying for desc in the XPath, query for the src attribute. Note: This assumes you know the image src attribute from the user submission. if you don't update the question, please.

Comment: @Gordon - YES! I seriously feel so dumb right now ha. It's working great!  Thanks a million!